# jQuery-UI integration with RichFaces 4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to add **jQuery-UI** functionnalities to an existing **JSF2** + **RichFaces 4** project. So far, I am not able to get it working.

Here is the xhtml code used :

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="jquery.ui/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
<h:outputScript name="jquery.ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" target="head" />

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            alert('test1');
            jQuery("#potatoe").resizable();
            alert('test2');
        }
    );
</script>

<div id="potatoe" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;"></div>
```

In the console (Firefox) I get the error `obj is undefined` from the **jQuery-UI** JS file and there is no **test2** alert. The line number wont be useful, but here is the code of the defective line :

```
},each:function(obj,callback,args){var name,i=0,length=obj.length,isObj=length===undefined||jQuery.isFunction(obj);
```

---

I've verified, the jQuery and jQuery-UI scripts are loaded properly in the browser. I've also tested this small code using the exact same files :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    alert('test1');
                    jQuery("#test").draggable(
                        {
                            grid: [50, 50]
                        }
                    );
                    jQuery("#test").resizable(
                        {
                            grid: 50
                        }
                    );
                    alert('test2');
                }
            );
        </script>
        <div id="test" style="width: 150px;height: 150px;background-color: red;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it is working properly. The jquery.js is **jQuery 1.8.2**, file provided with **RichFaces 4** saved from the website. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the error come from, jquery.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some conflict between jQuery and JQueryUI. The error occurs when the widget factory tries to register the `ui.mouse` widget and fails because widget doesn't contain all the variables it supposed to contain (specifically _childConstructor).

You can fix this by upgrading to RF 4.3, it uses jQuery 1.8.3 and it seems to work alright. Or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19827400/1818198) by rewriting the jQueryUI.

Comment: So why if I download the exact jquery.js file from the RichFaces/JSF2 website and do a simple html file (as explained) it works?

Comment: Well I don't know how it fixed it, but it works using RichFaces 4.3.4 Final (which only switch from jQuery 1.8.2 to 1.8.3).

Comment: RichFaces 4.3 use some widgets from jQueryUI 1.9.2, and they're being packed in the `packed.js` (including `ui.mouse`) it actually prevents the `ui.mouse` from 1.10.3 from failing. It's weird.